# How to create a filter in Django with two different status

Tags: python, django

I want to create a filter in Django admin which would return records with two different statuses by single "filter" defined as one of:

```
def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
    return (
        ('1', 'class 1'),
        ('2', 'class 2'),
        ('3', 'class 3'),
        ('4', 'class 3')
    )
```

I'm using an API that returns to me **all** statuses with two extra statuses which I don't need.

```
def queryset(self, request, queryset):
    if self.value() == 'all':
        return queryset.filter()
    else:
        return queryset.filter(client__status=self.value())
```

In my *filter list* I want to have just one logical item `clients with status x` which would give me all clients with status M and status N.

Comment: `I need it brings me to different status in one filter.` I don't seem to get it, can you please explain a little bit more on what you're trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def queryset(self, request, queryset):
    if self.value() == 'all':
        return queryset.all()
    elif self.value() == 'clients with status x':
        return queryset.filter(client__status__in=['M', 'N', ])
    else:
        return queryset.filter(client__status=self.value())
```